# How can I obtain a user's top tags with one call from the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I was trying to fetch some Stack Overflow users using the following procedure:

1. Fetch the users with https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids.
2. For each user id, fetch the top tags with https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-tags-on-users.
3. Programmatically match them using `user_id` and `account_id`.
4. Keep only the records with the `tag_name` I want.

Can this be done in a single step?

Comment: I guess it's not possible. But if you worry about quota, you can [register](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) your app and increase it from 300 to 10000.

Comment: It wasn't a concern about quota, but rather of directly obtaining the profiles I am interested, rather than scouting through a bunch of them to *then* find the tags.